# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'user profile.PRIMARY'")

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am very new to Django, creating rest API for my android application

In my signup form I am taking parameter like email, password, firstname, lastname, contact etc...
Every time new user signup, user profile data will also created based on that specific user id and those user id will should be unique in both the tables.

When I am trying to signup, facing the below issue :
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'user profile.PRIMARY'")

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete, post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.conf import settings
import uuid

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
   def create_user(self, email, password=None):
     if not email:
        raise ValueError('User must have an email address')

     user = self.model(
        email = self.email,
    )
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
   objects = UserManager()
   email = models.EmailField(unique=True, db_index=True)
   is_active = models.BooleanField('active', default=True)
   is_admin = models.BooleanField('admin', default=False)

   USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

   ordering = ('id',)

   def is_staff(self):
     return self.is_admin

   def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
     return True

   def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    return True

   def get_short_name(self):
     return self.email

   def get_full_name(self):
    return self.email

   def __unicode__(self):
    return self.email

   class Meta:
    db_table = 'user'

class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, 
   unique=True)
   first_name = models.TextField(max_length = 20, blank = False, default = '')
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = False, default = '')
   contact = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = False, default = '')
   gender = models.CharField(max_length = 2, blank = False, default = '')
   device = models.CharField(max_length = 2, blank = False, default = 0)
   # profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=None, height_field=None, width_field=None, 
   max_length=100, null = )
   date_registered = models.DateTimeField(default=now, blank=True)


def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user = instance)
post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender = User, dispatch_uid = "create user signal")

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.userprofile.save()
post_save.connect(save_user_profile, sender = User, dispatch_uid = "save user signal")

@receiver(post_delete, sender=User)
def delete_user(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
    try:
        instance.user
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return 'User does not exist'
    else:
        instance.user.delete()

class Meta:
    db_table = 'User Profile'
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from foodlApp.models import *
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model



class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = UserProfile
      fields = ['first_name', 
      'last_name', 'contact', 
      'gender', 'device', 'date_registered']

  # def create(self, validated_data):
  #     user = get_user_model().objects.create(email=validated_data['email'])
  #     user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
  #     user.save()

  #     profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user = user)
  #     return profile

 class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = UserProfileSerializer(required=True)
    class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ('email', 'password', 'profile')
    def create(self, validated_data):
       # create user 
       user = User.objects.create(
        email = validated_data['email'],
        )
       user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
       user.save()
       profile_data = validated_data['profile']
       # create profile
       profile = UserProfile.objects.create(
        user = user,
        first_name = profile_data['first_name'],
        last_name = profile_data['last_name'],
        contact = profile_data['contact'],
        gender = profile_data['gender'],
        device = profile_data['device'],
    )
    return user
```

views.py

```
class UserView(APIView):
   def post(self, request):
      if User.objects.filter(email = request.data.get('email')).exists():
        return Response({'message' : 'User already exists'})
        
      else :
        serializer = UserSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: You have two receiving functions for the User post_save signal?

Comment: The cause seems to be because `UserProfile` is created in the signal and then again in the `create` method of `UserSerializer`. Can you post the whole traceback